# Добавление переменной в метод. Excel

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь добавить путь до excel файла используя переменную. Путь получаю DoDragDrop методом. В переменной у меня string  вида C:\Path\File.Пробовал вот так:

```
excelApp.Workbooks.Add(@filePath); 
excelApp.Workbooks.Add(filePath);

excelApp.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Path\File"); // вот так работает без переменной
```

Пытался прибавить @" в начало и " в конец переменной. Не работает. Получаю исключение вида  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Путь получаю

```
string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
string filePath = files[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Для открытия файла используйте метод `Open`. Он возвращает открытую книгу

Попробуйте так

```
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
var currentWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fullPath);
```

или

```
string directoryName = @"C:\Path";
string filename = "File.xlsx";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(directoryName, filename);
var currentWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fullPath);
```

ну или так (C#6 и выше)

```
var currentWorkbook =  excelApp.Workbooks.Open($@"{ fullPath}");
```

Comment: Путь получаю DoDragDrop  методом. Добавил как выше. Может можно символами отделить  в  (@"Path") ,переменную от кавычек. Показав,что это именно переменная.

Comment: А в `filePath` после `filePath = files[0];` хранится же "C:\Path\File"? Просто я немного не понял, почему через `Path.GetFullPath(filePath)` не получается

Comment: Полный путь без кавычек. C:\Users\user\Desktop\export_47.xls

Comment: excelApp.Workbooks.Add($@"{fullPath}"); открывает новый файл excel и всё

Comment: тогда я не понял, что вы хотите получить. Я понял, что проблема с экранированием слэша в строке.

Comment: Открыть excel документ по пути,которое может быть случайным. Путь находиться,когда пользователь перетаскивает файл в форму программы. У меня есть алгоритм работы со строками файла и сделанная форма. Я пытаюсь их соединить.

Comment: @Олег Посмотрите измененный ответ, у меня нужная мне книга открылась